# Textarea autogrow not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, textarea, autogrow

What I'm trying is to make Textarea autogrow when you enter text or paste some text in it. It is working fine with IE7, IE8 and IE9, Firefox. But, in OPERA, CHROME and SAFARI it is auto growing even I click functional keys/additional keys like Shift, Ctrl, Down Arrow, Up Arrow, Left Arrow, Right Arrow, Home, End, Delete, etc., also.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function txtareaAutoGrow(txtar, clkBtn){
    // txtareaAutoGrow() start here
$("#"+txtar).height(18);

    $("#"+txtar).keyup(function(){
        if ($("#"+txtar).height() <= 18){
            $(this).height(18);
            }
        else {
            $(this).height($("#"+txtar).prop("scrollHeight"));
            $("#"+txtar).bind('paste', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                $("#"+txtar).height($("#"+txtar).prop("scrollHeight"));
            }, 100);            
    });
            }
        });


    $("#"+clkBtn).click(function(){
        if ($("#"+txtar).height() <= 18){
                $("#"+txtar).height($("#"+txtar).prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
            else {
                    $("#"+txtar).height(18);
                }
        });
    // txtareaAutoGrow() end here
};
</script>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Auto Resize TEXTAREA</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
        overflow:hidden;
        resize: none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autoresizeTextarea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    txtareaAutoGrow("txtar1", "btnXpand1");
    txtareaAutoGrow("txtar2", "btnXpand2");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    <textarea cols="100" id="txtar1"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="btnXpand1" value="Expand/Collapse" />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <textarea cols="100" id="txtar2"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="btnXpand2" value="Expand/Collapse" />
</p>
<p>
    <!--<input type="button" id="Heght" value="Height" />
    <input type="button" id="scrlHeight" value="Scroll Height" />
    <input type="button" id="btnXpand" value="Expand/Collapse" />-->
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would work in some browsers, but as far as I can tell you're setting the height to 18, then you're checking to see if it is 18 or below, and if it is, you're setting it to 18. As the height is set and there is no visible overflow, the height will never be more than 18, so it can't work.

If you check to see if it's just less than 18 it seems to work fine for me ? Also, it's probably not a bad idea to just cache that selector you keep using everywhere :

```
function txtareaAutoGrow(txtar, clkBtn) {
    var txtA = $("#" + txtar);

    txtA.height(18).keyup(function() {
        if (txtA.height() < 18) {
            $(this).height(18);
        }
        else {
            $(this).height(txtA.prop("scrollHeight"));
            txtA.bind('paste', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    txtA.height(txtA.prop("scrollHeight"));
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    });

    $("#" + clkBtn).click(function() {
        if (txtA.height() < 18) {
            txtA.height(txtA.prop("scrollHeight"));
        }
        else {
            txtA.height(18);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    txtareaAutoGrow("txtar1", "btnXpand1");
    txtareaAutoGrow("txtar2", "btnXpand2");
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SekM9/)

Comment: I don't really get it? Are you saying the textarea increases in height when hitting the arrow keys, shift etc. and is it doing this in the fiddle posted above as well??

Comment: Create a HTML page with the code and open it with Google Chrome. Now, try adding some text. Textarea is increasing for every keyup.

Comment: Works fine for me, but the problem you're getting is because it keeps adding the padding/margin on every keystroke, so set padding/margin to zero, and the problem disappears, and then adjust the size by setting the height to 20 instead of 18 if you have to, that way it will add the right numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Its working fine with a small issue. When I remove some text using Backspace or Delete button or some other way. Textarea height is not reducing in Chrome. The same functionality is fine with Internet Explorer.